# Android: Scale up width of ImageView in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap, imageview

In my app I'm generating a bunch of Bitmaps at runtime to show in a GridView. The generated Bitmaps consist only of rectangular shapes and about five different colors.

If I make them big, they get scaled down nicely, but I get OutOfMemoryExceptions. But when I make them small, they're not scaled up to fit the column width. I think ImageView can't help me, because it doesn't know the final column with. Setting stretchMode to columnWidth in the GridView didn't help.

Setting adjustViewBounds to true on the ImageView helped with large Bitmaps, but it doesn't help for upscaling.

Is it somehow possible to scale the ImageView with the underlying Bitmap to the maximum column width of the GridView? This would be my preferred solution.

If not, can I determine the columnWidth of the GridView in advance to just generate the bitmap accordingly? (I don't like this solution that much, because I suspect that on devices with large screens I might run into OutOfMemoryExceptions again.)

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices.

**METHOD 1:**

*Optimize your images by using any online image compression sites . For example   https://tinypng.com .TinyPNG uses smart lossy compression techniques to reduce the file size of your PNG files. By selectively decreasing the number of colors in the image, fewer bytes are required to store the data. The effect is nearly invisible but it makes a very large difference in file size!*

**METHOD 2:**

*Load your images using third party libraries like [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glidehttps://github.com/bumptech/glide) .. these libraries aims to provide a powerful, flexible and highly customizable instrument for image loading, caching and displaying. It provides a lot of configuration options and good control over the image loading and caching process.*

Comment: I **generate** the Bitmaps in my app. They don't get loaded from anywhere.

Comment: these libraries use multi threading for loading images into gridview/listview,so u wont suffer with OutOfMemory exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Since you generate the bitmaps in your app, you can use libraries like Picasso to display them. Picasso will handle the memory on your behalf and you need not worry about OutOfMemory Exceptions.